# What does this HP warning sound mean?

Tags: bios

I have a HP Compaq Elite 8300 MT with a Nvidia Quadro k640, 32GB RAM, and running CentOS 7.

When I play a computationally intensive game (like Minecraft with shaders), the PC makes a loud warning sound.

It sounds like a square wave going from a high frequency to a low one.  It's about 1 second long and repeats until I close the program (works only sometimes) or I shutdown the PC.

This does not happen when I render a Blender project with cylces over days!

So what does the warning sound mean? Could it be the power supply?

Comment: Have you checked your temps using Speccy for windows. Maybe its getting too hot? Or another venture is maybe HP has a warning for applications that are using a huge amount of battery? Check the HP software and BIOS for this setting. Either way you can turn the warning sound off by accessing the BIOS Settings and disabling this

Comment: The problem is i have a linux system. I also dont find a solution to turn the sound off in bios. I disabled the internal speaker, without effect.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the PC was just overheating.
Since I moved it away from  the wall, it hasn't made this sound anymore.